# generate ALL possible combinations from a number of lists

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, method-combination

Salam,
I want to get list of combinations  that represents every unique combination of all values in my list of lists. for example, have a list that containes a list of Sessions and i want a combination from each list of sessions:

```
My List of lists 
     {   List of Sessions1[S1,S2,S3]
         List of Sessions2[S4,S5]
         List of Sessions3[S6,S7]
     }
```

the List i get is

```
   List result
              {
               List combination 1[S1,S4,S6]
              List combination 2[S1,S4,S7]
           List combination 3[S1,S5,S6]
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have a method and it works but the problem is with the variable j cause my lists are too big so when it passes 9223372036854775807  (2^63-1) it starts giving negative values and it ruins the progress
here's my code

```
 public List<List<Seance>> allUniqueCombinations1(List<List<Seance>> dataStructure) throws SQLException {
        int n = dataStructure.size();
        long solutions = 1;
        for (List vector : dataStructure) {
            solutions *= vector.size(); if(solutions>1000000000) break;//this condition is for the same problem
        }
        List<List<Seance>> allCombinations = new LinkedList();     

        for (int i = 0; i < solutions; i++) {
         List<List<List<Seance>>> liste = new LinkedList();        
              List<Seance> combination = new LinkedList();
                 long j = 1;
               List<List<Seance>> data = new LinkedList();
                data = dataStructure;                
                int u = 0;
                for (int a=0;a< data.size();a++) {
                   List vec =(List<Seance>) data.get(a);

                    combination.add((Seance) vec.get((i / (int)j) % vec.size()));
                    j *= vec.size();
  data = remouve_conflicts(data, combination.get(u),u);//this removes all the sessions that will make a conflict with the session chosen in order not to appear in my combinition
                    u++;

                }  

            }


        return allCombinations;
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: `BigInteger solutions = new BigInteger("1")` instead of `long`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly you don't have to pre-calculate the number of permutations. Instead you can use the "odometer" approach, keeping an array of indexes into your list of input lists, and incrementing the "odometer" at each iteration.

```
List<List<String>> input = new ArrayList<>();
input.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"S1", "S2", "S3"}));
input.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"S4", "S5"}));
input.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"S6", "S7"}));

int[] idx = new int[input.size()];

List<String> base  = new ArrayList<>();
for(List<String> sl : input) base.add(sl.get(0));

List<List<String>> allCombinations  = new ArrayList<>();

while(true)
{
  allCombinations.add(new ArrayList<>(base));

  int k=idx.length-1;
  for(; k>=0; k--)
  {
    idx[k] += 1;
    if(idx[k] < input.get(k).size()) 
    {
      base.set(k, input.get(k).get(idx[k]));
      break;
    }
    idx[k] = 0;
    base.set(k, input.get(k).get(idx[k]));
  }
  if(k < 0) break;          
}

for(List<String> combo : allCombinations)
    System.out.println(combo);
```

Output:

```
[S1, S4, S6]
[S1, S4, S7]
[S1, S5, S6]
[S1, S5, S7]
[S2, S4, S6]
[S2, S4, S7]
[S2, S5, S6]
[S2, S5, S7]
[S3, S4, S6]
[S3, S4, S7]
[S3, S5, S6]
[S3, S5, S7]
```

Comment: but like this how can i minimise the complexity of algorithm cz i have a very big list.. for example i don't want S1 with S4 so i avoid all combination that gother S1 with S4

Answer (score 0):

The limit for `Long` is `Long.MAX_VALUE` which equates to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. On passing that value, it wraps around to `Long.MIN_VALUE` which equates to -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.

That is, `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which is what you're experiencing.

Use the datatype `BigInt`, which should suit your purpose; in theory it has no upper bound, and is practically bound by your available memory(which is a lot for a variable).